# Moving intent into if statement

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have following code:

```
buttons[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
  @Override 
  public void onClick(View v) 
  {
    try{
      startActivity(new Intent(names[x][0]));
    }
    catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
      if (x==1) {
        Intent intent = newIntent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id=uk.co.nickfines.RealCalc"));
      }
    }
    try {
      startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException f) {
      // Google Play Store app not available.
    }
  }
});
```

It started to give `intent cannot be resolved to a variable` error for `startActivity(intent)` after I put `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id=uk.co.nickfines.RealCalc")` into `if` statement. Everything worked fine before I did this. What is the problem?

Comment: @QAMAR the code doesn't compile, there is no logcat...

Comment: You should **REALLY** format your code...

Comment: You have too many brackets. You probably added extra(s) when you put in the if statement. Properly indent your code and trace each open bracket to its matching closing bracket, once you get rid of the extras you'll be on your way.

Comment: You're not handing a scendario when `x != 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `intent` is defined inside the block, therefore it is visible into the block only. If you want to use it in other block move its definition upper. Or move starting activity to your `catch` block. Anyway you have nothing to do with it in other places because only if exception was thrown and `x==1` intent exists.

And more recommendation. There are common java coding convention. It is *extremely* hard to read your code. I have formatted it for you and fixed your problem. Here is how it should look like.

```
    buttons[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override 
        public void onClick(View v) {
        try{
            startActivity(new Intent(names[x][0]));
        } catch(ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            if (x==1) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id=uk.co.nickfines.RealCalc"));
                try {
                    startActivity(intent);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException f) {
                }
            }
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
buttons[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        Intent intent;
        try{
            startActivity(new Intent(names[x][0]));
        }
        catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
            if (x==1) {
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id=uk.co.nickfines.RealCalc"));
            }
        }
        try {
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException f) {
        // Google Play Store app not available.
        }
    }
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
);
```

Your intent is local to the if statement

Answer (score 1):

Please learn some basic Java before attempting to create apps.

Here, you define intent only in the catch block:

```
catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
    if (x==1) {Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id=uk.co.nickfines.RealCalc"));
}
```

The scope of intent is only in that block so `startActivity(intent);` will give a compiler error as you are seeing.

```
Intent intent;
try{
    startActivity(new Intent(names[x][0]));
} catch(ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    if (x==1){
       intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id=uk.co.nickfines.RealCalc"));
    }
}
try {
    if(intent!=null){
        startActivity(intent);
    }
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException f) {
    // Google Play Store app not available.
}
```

That `if(x==1)` looks evil.  What's it doing?